# Output generated DDL for ecto migrations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is it possible to output the DDL generated by migrations in ecto? I would imagine a command similar to:

`mix ecto.migrate --verbose`

If we have a `create_user` migration, it would output something like:

`CREATE TABLE users(
  id int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  username varchar(255) not null
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now possible to output the migration SQL like this:

```
 mix ecto.migrate --log-sql > file.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, according to the latest [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.html), there's no option like that.
Consider creating issue for that in [Ecto](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues).